# QT5 attaching project name with every sourcefile name, compiling error

Tags: c++, qt, compiler-errors, qt5

i want to get started with QT. I donwloaded QT5 MINGW compiler with QT creator and i am trying to build the pre attached example named ***affine*** the problem is that the QT5 i think embed the project name with each of source file and thus gives error that file not found. some thing similar

```
    :-1: error: ..affinemain.cpp: No such file or directory
```

while the file name is just

```
    main.cpp
```

i don't know how to fix it. I searched lot on internet but could not found anything useful. 
I even try to compile from command prompt but i am not fimmiliar with command prompt compiling as i am new to QT and previously i am totally developed with IDE in visual studio and eclipse for java so i have no idea about the make file and compiler command line arguments. 
could some body please help me to fix this issue and can you tell please why compiler attaching project name with the source file name? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I have got the same problem and my solution may help you.

I am working with Qt5.0.1 now, and there are two distributions to work on windows with it: Qt5.0.1-mingw and Qt5.0.1-msvc2010.
I had to use mingw and there was a problem on my setup that "/" is ignored in path's.

So according to Qt Creator, compiler was called to process file mainwindow.cpp and this file was passed to it

```
g++ /*truncated*/ ..\qt-example\mainwindow.cpp
```

Below is the full compiler input:

```
g++ -c -pipe -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -g -frtti -Wall -Wextra -fexceptions -mthreads -DUNICODE -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_DECLARATIVE_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_OPENGL_ES_2 -DQT_OPENGL_ES_2_ANGLE -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I..\qt-example -I"..\..\..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\mingw47_32\include" -I"..\..\..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\mingw47_32\include\QtWidgets" -I"..\..\..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\mingw47_32\include\QtGui" -I"..\..\..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\mingw47_32\include\QtCore" -I"debug" -I"." -I"." -I"..\..\..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\mingw47_32\mkspecs\win32-g++" -o debug\mainwindow.o ..\qt-example\mainwindow.cpp
```

And the error produced.

```
g++.exe: error: ..qt-examplemainwindow.cpp: No such file or directory
g++.exe: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

So, we can see that "\" is ignored by the compiler and file name is merged with directory name.

The solution to that problem goes to the tools that are used - [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) (Minimalist ports of GCC and Binutils). And also [MSYS](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS) - a collection of GNU utilities such as bash, make, gawk and grep to allow building of applications and programs which depend on traditionally UNIX tools to be present. In our case - g++.

MSYS is not shipped with Qt5.0.1-mingw and g++ is not using it, but having MSYS available in your PATH environment variable breaks the system.

MSYS [is used](http://msysgit.github.com/) for git scm, which I have installed, so my path contains links to MSYS that goes bundled with git. So I have next paths in my PATH environment variable.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\git\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\git\cmd
```

I have not found how MSYS is used by Qt Creator or g++, or where it is linked, but when I have dropped next path from PATH:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\git\bin;
```

and restarted Qt Creator - g++ succeeded on compiling my file, it worked.
The question why/how it influences the Qt Creator/g++ that should not use MSYS utils installed with git is still open.

Comment: MSYS is not required for MinGW(-w64) GCC. You shouldn't have added `msysgit/bin` to your systemwide PATH. Remove that and chances are you'll have more luck after you rerun qmake. MSYSgit should install shortcuts to git Bash, which works without any PATH modifications. If you want to use basic git commands from cmd, keep the `../git/cmd` portion in PATH.

Comment: Right, MSYS is not required, but the question is why/how it breaks the g++. Because it does break it. I have not added 'sysgit/bin' on purpose - they are added during the installation silently. As I said, both git(in Console2) and qmake work without them. Nice thing to add '../git/cmd' to PATH to get the git running from cmd. I will add this to the answer. Thank you.

Comment: where did you get your msysgit? Every time I install it it offers the choice to add either git/bin, git/cmd or nothing to PATH, with a big warning about adding git/bin to PATH.

Comment: I have installed it long ago from official site so I don't remember all the details now. However, I have just downloaded the latest version of Git (1.8.1.2) from http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list?q=full+installer+official+git, and tried it. You are right - it gives a choice. With big red warning :-) Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

i can´t comment.

important : delete all the files in the release and debug folder (compiled version) before try the tips of the autor ...